# How trasmit a dictionary in JSON form

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a dictionary in JSON form, like this:

```
$user = "{ name: Mary , born: 1963, money: 213 }";
```

I need to pass it through this field:

```
<input type="hidden" name="custom" value="" >
```

and then insert it in the database:

```
INSERT INTO user ( name, born, money ) VALUE ( $name, $born, $money )
```

Comment: What you have is not a valid JSON. You are missing quotes around `Mary` :-). Also I wouldn't recommend you inserting JSON into the database. Databases are meant for storing data and not serialized data. So insert only the values and reconstruct the JSON later when needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as putting it in a hidden input is concerned, it is just text. So do with it what you would do with any other text. (i.e. run htmlspecialchars over it and drop it in there).

Then use PHP's [JSON functions](http://php.net/json) to turn it into a data structure then you can pick the bits you care about out of and stuck them into a [prepared SQL statement](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php).